# Value for JSON Object on page is resolving to "." DOT for input tag : accept

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, jsp

I am using Angular and on my JSP Page for input type I am using as below.
: input type="file" ng-show="false" accept="{{allowedExtensions}}" />
..
Value for allowedExtension value is
allowedExtensions : ['application/pdf', 'image/jpeg'].

Problem : When value is resolved on pagem it is coming as 
accept=".application/pdf,.image/jpeg" instead of accept="application/pdf,image/jpeg".

Comment: There is only one [*JSON object*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-json-object), the one that's a property of the global object.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Lhwr1rrs/

Any more demos?